# How do I style a word document exported from a webpage in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I'm trying to export text retrieved from a database into a word document in VB.Net and while I have a working example, I need to figure out how to style some sections of the document appropriately.

I have found a few working examples from MS Online resources (such as [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383) one), which I've found can cover some basics:

```
para.Range.Text = "Quad Chart"
para.Range.Style = "Heading 1"
para.Range.Bold.Font = True
```

But it doesn't cover even some of the simplest of formatting such as:

- How you align the text (left, right, center)?
- How you specify letting?
- How do you start a list style?

What I'm trying to find is either a straight answer to these or (even better), a definitive list of the commands that would allow most any formatting.

Also, I would prefer not using Spire, which seems to be a common answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [VBA object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) describes all the classes, their methods and properties that you can use for the marking up of content.

Your suggestion to use styles is strongly recommended as a way of separating your code from the presentation. Create a document template (.dot or .dotx, depending on Word version) and attach this to your documents. Then, when the document is opened, it will inherit layout and presentation from the template and be correctly rendered.

The list creation is a little intricate as you will need to restart the list if you are using numbering.

If you are interested in a completely different approach, you can look at [Applying an XSLT Transform in the Microsoft Office Word 2003 XML Software Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee364545%28v=office.11%29.aspx). This describes how to generate XML documents and using XSL transforms to describe the presentation. More general, but definitely more complex to set up.

Your preferred approach will depend on whether you want to generate native documents with a template, or to require your users to install the transform using the tools in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very thorough. I also found this [Word Document Object Map](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/HV080600108.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HV080600090) and it's the most comprehensive guide I've seen so far. I would use templates if our server allowed it, which it may or may not, and I would like to avoid forcing the user to install anything so I may go with simple styles.

Comment: You could create the styles you require and embed them into the document you create. This will increase the document size, but once you work out how to update the document, changes will not be too difficult, but can't be left only yto a technical writer maintaining the template.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a few examples. Office VBA is a cut down version of VB6, so why not record some macros in Word, open the VB editor and look at what it does. It's also the easiest way to navigate the help on the Word object model.